# How can I map this asynchronous NPM twit function onto an array?

Tags: javascript, twitter, foreach, promise, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to figure out how to map this async function onto an array that I am using. The code that I tried is returned undefined since the promise isn't completing.

I am using NPM twit and this is the function that is supposed to return a number when an ID is passed into it

```
ids = ['1084212656771350532','2450457644','1244639845743570948','1081269935031140353','1227966230511980550','752215003143430145']

T.get('statuses/user_timeline', { user_id: id, count: 100, exclude_replies: true, include_rts: false }, function (err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('err');
    } else {
        var rtTotal = 0;
        var likeTotal = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            rtTotal += data[i].retweet_count;
            var rtAverage = rtTotal / data.length;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            likeTotal += data[i].favorite_count;
            var likeAverage = likeTotal / data.length;

        }
    }

    var influenceScore = (.33 * rtAverage) + (.2 * likeAverage) + (.33 * (data[0].user.followers_count)) + (.14 * (data[0].user.statuses_count));
    console.log(influenceScore);
    return influenceScore;
})
```

For example the result should be an array with numerical values

```
[1123.11, 9200, 21882, 1011, 23110.22]
```